# Python, access to certain values in array

Tags: python, arrays, image, for-loop, pixel

I have an array of coordinates (y,x) refered to a specific pixels in an image fig300[0,:,:].
I want find these coordinates in my image and for these pixel change their intensity.

The output of my array, called brighter_spot is this:

```
array([[116, 159],
       [508, 106],
       [ 90, 752],
       [116, 159],
       [508, 106],
       [ 90, 752],
       [116, 159],
       [235, 206],
       [508, 106],
       [ 90, 752],
       [116, 159],
       [235, 206],
       [508, 106],
       [ 90, 752],
       [116, 159],
       [235, 206],
       [508, 106],
       [ 90, 752],
       [116, 159],
       [235, 206],
       [508, 106],
       [ 90, 752],
       [116, 159],
       [235, 206],
       [508, 106],
       [ 90, 752],
       [116, 159],
       [134, 380],
       [235, 206],
       [508, 106],
       [ 90, 752],
       [116, 159],
       [235, 206],
       [508, 106],
       [ 90, 752],
       [116, 159],
       [235, 206],
       [508, 106],
       [ 90, 752],
       [116, 159],
       [235, 206],
       [508, 106],
       [ 90, 752],
       [116, 159],
       [235, 206],
       [508, 106],
       [ 90, 752],
       [116, 159],
       [235, 206],
       [508, 106],
       [ 90, 752],
       [116, 159],
       [235, 206],
       [508, 106],
       [ 90, 752],
       [116, 159],
       [235, 206],
       [508, 106],
       [ 90, 752],
       [116, 159],
       [235, 206],
       [508, 106],
       [ 90, 752],
       [116, 159],
       [235, 206],
       [508, 106],
       [ 90, 752],
       [116, 159],
       [235, 206],
       [508, 106],
       [ 90, 752],
       [116, 159],
       [235, 206],
       [508, 106],
       [ 90, 752],
       [116, 159],
       [235, 206],
       [508, 106],
       [ 90, 752],
       [116, 159],
       [235, 206],
       [508, 106],
       [ 90, 752],
       [116, 159],
       [235, 206],
       [508, 106]], dtype=int64)
```

I built the for-loop in this manner:

```
for y,x in brighter_spot:
        if fig300[0,y,x] == brighter_spot.any():
            fig300[0,y,x] = 0
```

The for-loop don't have any effect, I think that it don't run properly inside the array comparing each couple.
How could I fix it?

Comment: Sorry, in the first line of for-loop there isn't the word "range", it was a typing error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for y in range(brighter_spot):
    for x in range(y):
        if np.isin(brighter_spot, fig300[0, y, x]).any():
            fig300[0,y,x] = 0
```

Comment: In this way the error message is: TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Answer (score 0):

"I want to find these coordinates in my image and for these pixel change their intensity".

Simply do

```
for x,y in brighter_spot:
    fig300[0,y,x] = ...
```

Not sure what you want to achieve with `brighter_spot.any()`. you should check the doc: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.any.html

This looks for any non None value in the array. In your case it always returns `true`, and you then compare a pixel value with a boolean at each iteration, what always returns `False`. That's why the for-loop doers not have any effect.